# What Application Website should I use with a test application for Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to write a small test application for Twitter as a personal project. To begin working on the project, I need a consumer key to identify and process my requests.

Since I'm just writing a test application, what should I enter under "Application Website" on the [registration form](http://dev.twitter.com/apps/new)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some code hosting service like http://sourceforge.net/ where you create a project and host your code.

Of course, it is just a link that you'd want to provide if you are really building a client.

Since this is a test application, it would not matter what you enter in "Application Website". By this, I mean that twitter does not check whether the code exists on that site or not. It is just for convenience.

Comment: @anonymous - You should accept Anirudh's answer if it was what you needed.